# Non nested for loops in a single line for creating list in python

Tags: python, list

I am a novice in python. I wanted to create a list in a single line:

```
>>> x = [[-1, y] for y in range(-1, 2), [0, 1], [1, z] for z in range(1, -2, -1), [0, -1]]
```

to get :

```
>>>> x = [[-1, -1], [-1, 0], [-1, 1], [0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 0], [1, -1], [0, -1]]
```

but it gave error : name 'z' is not defined. So I had to do it with for loops and single pairs on separate lines, appending each time. Before that I did :

```
>>> x = [[-1, y] for y in range(-1, 2),[0, 1]]
>>> x
[[-1, [-1, 0, 1]], [-1, [0, 1]]]
```

which tells me y is taken as iterator of for loop as well as [0, 1]. I am wrongly corelating comma in C and python. How do I achieve what I intend to do (in a single line) ? (I know that I could do it directly since its a small range. But what if there was a bigger one?)

Comment: Is the order random on purpose? I initially thought you meant to perform `[ [y,z] for y in range(-1, 2) for z in range(-1, 2)]`. Please explain yourself better.

Comment: A list comprehension produces a homogenous list. You are trying to create a heterogenous list, one that contains both lists of ints (e.g. `[-1, -1]`) and lists of lists of ints (`[[1,1], [1,0], [1, -1]]`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should concatenate lists, and put nested list to brackets

```
>>> [[-1, y] for y in range(-1, 2)] + [[0, 1], [[1, z] for z in range(1, -2, -1)], [0, -1]]
[[-1, -1], [-1, 0], [-1, 1], [0, 1], [[1, 1], [1, 0], [1, -1]], [0, -1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html). Not sure from your question whether you're going to want `product`, `permutations` or `combinations` but I think one of those will be what you need.

edit: On closer inspection, you're doing something much simpler and you just missed a few brackets. Try:

```
x = [[[-1, y] for y in range(-1, 2)], [0, 1], [[1, z] for z in range(1, -2, -1)], [0, -1]]
```

List comprehensions go in their own set of brackets, it's similar to the syntax of a list literal but not the same.

edit 2:

> Before that I did :
>
> ```
> x = [[-1, y] for y in range(-1, 2),[0, 1]]
> x [[-1, [-1, 0, 1]], [-1, [0, 1]]]
> ```
>
> which tells me y is taken as iterator of for loop as well as [0, 1]. I
>   am wrongly corelating comma in C and python. How do I achieve what I
>   intend to do (in a single line) ? (I know that I could do it directly
>   since its a small range. But what if there was a bigger one?)

Yes you're misunderstanding what your comma is doing there. It's turning the 2nd part of your for loop into a tuple of `(range(-1,2), [0, 1])` (2 items). What you needed to do here was close your list comprehension after `range(-1,2)`, and then wrap the whole thing in square brackets to make it a literal list declaration:

`x = [[[-1, y] for y in range(-1, 2)],[0, 1]]`

As mentioned by @YuriyKovalev, it would probably be clearer to concat the lists like so:

`x = [[-1, y] for y in range(-1, 2)] + [0, 1]`